# Discord.py Simple reaction role

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a simple way to make a reaction role with my code setup. Every tutorial I've seen does it differently so I'm confused

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$krole'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="lorem ipsum", 
        description="lorem ipsum", 
        )
```

I need that when someone reacts to the embed with a specific emoji it will assign them a role

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your code has no relation with react roles.

Comment: @Ceres yes, because i dont know how to do it. thats why imasknig

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a "code it for me" type of site, please make an honest attempt to solve the problem, you can also look at some [examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reaction_roles.py) online. Sorry but I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest listening for [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) And then looking at the `str(payload.emoji)` and comparing it to your desired emoji, and then comparing `payload.channel_id` and `payload.message_id` to the channel and message id of the reaction role.